# How to connect the css file to the end of the header on wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress

I need to connect a css file so that all css files of the site could be edited from it
including files like botton.min.css

through the functions.php file it is not displayed further
static2.keep4u.ru/2018/11/10/nnnnnd8073f6a38d659d0.jpg

for output I used

```
 function spon_style() {


 wp_enqueue_style( 'Me_css_code', get_template_directory_uri() . '/spon.css', array(), '1.0' );

 }
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'spon_style' );
```

Comment: Add priority as 3rd parameter to [add_action()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/)? `Lower numbers correspond with earlier execution, and functions with the same priority are executed in the order in which they were added to the action. Default value: 10`

Answer (score 0):

Just access your header.php file and add style before  tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/spon.css" />
```